# How to create the function using Expression linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression

I have the following class

```
public class ProdutoTipo : IAuditable
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string MiniNome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public int? Ordem { get; set; }

    public virtual Foto ImagemExibicao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProdutoCategoria> Categorias { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public bool PaginaInicial { get; set; }

    public ProdutoTipo() { ID = Guid.NewGuid(); }
}
```

I need a function that search the repository and returns true or false
**But this search can be using any field of the class!**

### As far as I arrived

```
public bool Existe<TProperty, TComparer>(Expression<Func<ProdutoTipo, TProperty>> entityExpression, TComparer valor)
{
    return Repository.ProdutoTipos.Any(p => /*entityExpression == valor ?????*/);
}
```

**Would like to use the function like this ...**

```
Existe(p => p.Nome, "Value to comparer!");
```

Thank you all!

Comment: what kind of repository is this? Is this still Linq to Objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
Func<ProdutoTipo, TProperty> getter = entityExpression.Compile();
Repository.ProdutoTipos.Any(p => getter(p).Equals(valor));
```

But you might as well do this:

```
public bool Existe<TProperty, TComparer>(Expression<Func<ProdutoTipo, bool>> expression)  
{  
    return Repository.ProdutoTipos.Any(expression);  
}
```

And call:

```
Existe(p => p.Nome == "Value to comparer!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public bool Existe<TProperty, TComparer>(Expression<Func<ProdutoTipo, TProperty>> entityExpression, TComparer valor)
{
    entityExpression.Compile()(Repository.ProdutoTipos);
}
```