# How to change calculation type using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list based on some ID or string value I want to change calculation type over group by

```
var result = from r in mlist
             group r by new
                     {
                         r.ParameterId,
                         r.WId,

                     } into g
             select new
                     {
                         g.Key.ParameterId,
                         g.Key.WId,
                         Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value)
                     };
```

I want to replace this **linq** Sum with a custom method, which will return calculated result based on some calculation type like avg, sum etc.

May be something like this:

```
var result = from r in mlist
             group r by new
                     {
                         r.ParameterId,
                         r.WId,
                     } into g
             select new
                     {
                         g.Key.ParameterId,
                         g.Key.WId,
                         Value = g.CustomMethod(x => x.Value, x.calctype)
                     };
```

Comment: Is this going to hit the database? Or in memory? In any case, it's as simple as writing an `if`/`switch` statement in your custom method.

Comment: Where does the second `x` come from in `g.CustomMethod(x => x.Value, x.calctype)`? Maybe it's possible to add all possible functions in a dictionary with `calctype` as key. In that case you can call it like `dict[<calctype>](g, x => x.Value)`. Using that you're not able to call it like an extension method.

Comment: Do you need to specifically pass the x.value and x.calctype to the CustomMethod? Wouldn't it work if you have access to the full r object iinside the CustomMethod?

Comment: Rob: its in memory- i cant call custommethod in same way as i mention please suggest better way to call method.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the set of methods that you can use for LINQ queries by adding extension methods to the IEnumerable interface. For example, in addition to the standard average or maximum operations, you can create a custom aggregate method to compute a single value from a sequence of values. You can also create a method that works as a custom filter or a specific data transform for a sequence of values and returns a new sequence.

```
public static class LINQExtension
{
    public static double Median(this IEnumerable<double> source)
    {
        if (source.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot compute median for an empty set.");
        }

        var sortedList = from number in source
                         orderby number
                         select number;

        int itemIndex = (int)sortedList.Count() / 2;

        if (sortedList.Count() % 2 == 0)
        {
            // Even number of items.
            return (sortedList.ElementAt(itemIndex) + sortedList.ElementAt(itemIndex - 1)) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            // Odd number of items.
            return sortedList.ElementAt(itemIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

[Source: Add Custom Methods for LINQ Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981895.aspx)

You would also like to view [Create the function using Expression linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9846072/3796048)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your own extention method, somethig like this:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static int CustomMethod<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector, Func<TSource, int> type)
    {
        var sum = 0;
        source.ToList().ForEach(x => sum += selector(x) * type(x));
        return sum;
    }
}
```

And you will execute it this way, your second code listing will not be compiled:

```
Value = g.CustomMethod(x => x.Value, x => x.calctype)
```

If you want one calctype for all items you can write this:

```
Value = g.CustomMethod(x => x.Value, x => 123);
```